# No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.If() is applicable for argument types

Tags: groovy

```
`def map = message.getHeaders();
String value = map.get("x-forwarded-for");
String\[\] splitterValues = value != null ? value.split(",") : null ;
If ( splitterValues != null && splitterValues.length \> 0 ) {
int i = 0;
int clientIPPosition = splitterValues.length -2;
def clientIP = splitterValues\[clientIPPosition\];
If ( clientIP != null && "123".equals(clientIP.trim()) ) {  
messageLog.setStringProperty("AllowListed clientIP", clientIP);
}  
}`
```

This is my code and this is my first time with groovy scripts, Can someone please help me
I need to pick the IP address using the above code

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `if` in Groovy only works in lowercase. Please try `if` instead of `If`.

Comment: I just cant thank you enough, My issue is resolved

Comment: Also may i request you to share a platform where i can debug the groovy scripts, i cant find anything in Groovy IDE

Comment: If you plan to dive deep into Groovy, you might consider IntelliJ IDEA. The debug information probably won't get much better than the error message you got, though.